# Why does LINQ not like inline date calculations?

Tags: c#, linq

This LINQ expression involving a DateTime calculation compiles fine:

```
var jobsSinceLastRun = _rep.GetJobs(j => j.CompletedDate > DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1));
```

But when you try and run it, an error is thrown:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime AddMonths(Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Easy enough to fix:

```
DateTime oneMonthAgo = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1);
var jobsSinceLastRun = _rep.GetJobs(j => j.CompletedDate > oneMonthAgo);
```

But the ease of that makes me wonder what, behind the scenes, is causing LINQ to reject the inline calculation? What part of the abstraction is failing?

Comment: It is "LINQ to Entities" that doesn't have code to write that expression properly in SQL that is complaining, not "LINQ". When you change to the second piece of code then LINQ to Entities sees a final value, and not the expression, and that value can easily be handled by the SQL using parameters.

Comment: Also, `j => j.CompletedDate > DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1)` would create a new instance every time the expression is evaluated, and that's probably not what you want

Comment: Just a thought... but with logic like this, your intent may be better achieved with `DateTime oneMonthAgo = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-1);`, otherwise things earlier on the same day could get missed.

Comment: @IvanStoev How did you determine the OP is using EF 6.x to mark that as duplicate?

Comment: @IvanStoev the question is about *why* this is not working but no *how* to do it so it should not be marked as duplicate.

Comment: @arekzyla That was my feeling rather, but the suggested dupe does also contain an explanation. It's not as clear as yours IMO, so this is kind of an interesting grey area.

Comment: @IvanStoev The question is "what  is causing LINQ to reject the inline calculation" and not "why AddMonths is not supported" so the answer explains that an expression tree is created including this inline calculations (so it's not evaluated before to a value as OP might thought). I think that's what is this question about and I can't find such explanation in a dupe question.

Comment: @IvanStoev I respect your work to try to keep SO clean of duplicates but here you are just wrong. The dupe does not provide an answer OP expects and there is no even a similar answer to this. The questions are not exactly the same thus this should not be marked as duplicate. In terms of inline addition with constants like `1 + 2` it is evaluated at compilation time so at runtime it will be just 3 thus an expression tree will not include the addition (unless there are variables) and it has nothing to do with what Linq-to-Entities supports. I don't think OP wants such level of detail.

Comment: @arekzyla Fair enough. I will rollback my edit with `entity-framework` tag (to bring question/answer back in more general scope) and retract the closure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because there is an expression tree created from the lambda including this inline caluclation. LINQ methods for `IQueryable` interface expects expression tree types not delegates. So for expression:

```
j => j.CompletedDate > DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1)
```

The expression visitor for EF 6 tries to convert `DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1)` to SQL which can't because translation of this method is not supported. For example in EF Core it is supported so the expression can be translated. For expression:

```
j => j.CompletedDate > oneMonthAgo
```

The expression visitor can convert `oneMonthAgo` to SQL because it's a variable which value can be just included in SQL.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `Entity Framework 6.x` and above - you can use [DbFunctions Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions(v=vs.113).aspx) to use `DateTime` calculations for LINQ to Entities queries:

```
var jobsSinceLastRun = _rep.GetJobs(j => j.CompletedDate > DbFunctions.AddMonths(DateTime.Now, -1));
```

Comment: This assumes the OP is using specifically Entity Framework 6.x. I am not sure from where you got that assumption

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Thanks for note, I've updated my answer. I'm answering not only for to cover OP's needs, but for anyone else, who will find this helpful.